# Transposing X and Y on a plot

Tags: plotting, functions

This question has appeared in many forms online, but none directly apply to my problem. I have a quite complicated, albeit bijective function of the form

```
F: X->Y.
```

Concretely, here is the function of two variables, which I named "Graham":

```
Graham[d_, σ_] := 
Module[{β, ϵ0, h, m, e0, ϕ0},
h = 6.62606957*10^(-34);
ϵ0 = 8.8541878176*10^(-12);
m = 9.10938291*10^(-31);
e0 = 1.6*10^(-19);

β = 4/(((5*((3/5 2^(-1/3) (3/π)^(
2/3))*((ϵ0*
h^2)/(m*(e0)^(5/3)))*(d^(-5/3)*σ^(-1/3)))/
3)*(1/2)^(2/3))^(3/4)*Sqrt[5]);

ϕ0 = (Cosh[β/2])/(β*Sinh[β/2]) - 
1/(β*Sinh[β/2]);

Return[ϕ0]]
```

A relevant plot of this function would be

```
Plot[{Graham[10^-9, σ]}, {σ, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Graham function]

I want to reflect this function over the x=y line. I know how to do it point-wise and using listline plot and the transformation

```
rt = ReflectionTransform[{1, -1}];

rt[{x, y}]
{y, x}
```

but I'm sure there must exist a way to somehow reflect it around the identity x=y. Help is much appreciated!

Comment: closely related Q/As: [Reflect a Plot Object](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7859/125), [How can I transpose x and y axis on a Plot?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18655/125), [Combining two plots with inverted xy-axes](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46905/125).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a couple of approaches:

1. using `ParametricPlot`

   ```
   Quiet@ParametricPlot[{Graham[10^-9, t], t}, {t, 0, 1}, 
   AspectRatio -> Full]
   ```
2. Let `p` be your plot and just extract points:

   ```
   ListPlot[Reverse /@ First[Cases[p, Line[x__] :> x, -1]], 
   Joined -> True]
   ```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply, it totally works!