# Flipping the axes of a plot that is produced by a solution of NDSolve

Tags: plotting

I wish to rotate a plot in the simplest way possible.

I've tried these previously asked questions, but they did not help to produce a good result:

- [How can I transpose x and y axis on a Plot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18655/how-can-i-transpose-x-and-y-axis-on-a-plot?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
- [Transposing X and Y on a plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84624/transposing-x-and-y-on-a-plot)

Unlike another post, which the data is a list, here the data is an interpolating function, and I'm not able to reverse the axes:

- [How to rotate the curve but not the axes?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/135376/how-to-rotate-the-curve-but-not-the-axes)

Here is my sample code and output:

```
s = NDSolve[{x'[t] == -x[t] + 2 y[t], y'[t] == -4 y[t] x[t], 
   x[0] == 1, y[0] == 1}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 100}]

Plot[{Evaluate[x[t]] /. s, Evaluate[y[t]] /. s}, {t, 0, 100}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"x(t)", "y(t)"}, {{0.75, 0.75}, Center}]]
```

[image]

What I want to produce is something like

[image]

I'm looking for a simple implementation, in which I could perform all the plot options (filling, framing etc.).

Comment: @corey979, I've added this post to the body of the question, I cannot implement that procedure on an interpolating function that is produced by NDSolve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s = NDSolve[{x'[t] == -x[t] + 2 y[t], y'[t] == -4 y[t] x[t], 
    x[0] == 1, y[0] == 1}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 100}];
plot = Plot[{Evaluate[x[t]] /. s, Evaluate[y[t]] /. s}, {t, 0, 100}, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{"x(t)", "y(t)"}, Scaled[{0.75, 0.5}]]]
```

From [Mr. Wizard's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/135426/22013):

```
axisRotate = # /. {x_Point | x_Line | x_GraphicsComplex :> 
  MapAt[(#.{{0, -1}, {1, 0}}) &, x, 1]} &;
```

with inverted signs of the ticks:

```
Show[axisRotate@plot, AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio/1, PlotRange -> All, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, Table[{-i, i}, {i, 20, 100, 20}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a pretty simple way. I had to include the option `AxesOrigin->{0,0}`; otherwise the vertical axes did not turn up.

```
s=NDSolve[{x'[t]==-x[t]+2 y[t],y'[t]==-4 y[t] x[t],x[0]==1,y[0]==1},{x,y},{t,0,100}];

pic=Plot[{Evaluate[x[t]]/.s,Evaluate[y[t]]/.s},{t,0,100},PlotLegends->Placed[{"x(t)","y(t)"},{{0.75,0.75},Center}], AxesOrigin->{0,0}]
```

[image]

```
pic /.{ Line[pts_]:>Line[Reverse/@ pts], HoldPattern[PlotRange->pr_]:>(PlotRange->Reverse@pr)}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
pic= Plot[{Evaluate[x[t]] /. s, Evaluate[y[t]] /. s}, {t, 0, 100},PlotLegends -> Placed[{"x(t)", "y(t)"}, {{0.75, 0.75}, Center}]]
MapAt[Rotate[#, -Pi/2] &, pic, {1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering, but here the plot is not reversed/transposed

Comment: Sorry, now I got your question